# unable to pass test cases in codewar

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement

The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollars bill. A "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.

Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.

Can Vasya sell a ticket to each person and give the change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people follow in the line?

Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to each person and give the change. Otherwise return NO.

Eg.

```
Line.Tickets(new int[] {25, 25, 50}) // => YES
```

I was able to pass 10 test cases out of 11 but for 1 test case it showing that my result is wrong.

Say, 
Input=>`Line.Tickets(new int[] {25,50,25,100})` 
My code's output=

> NO

If first person has 25$ bill->count25=1 and count50=0 ,if second person has 50 dollar bill->count50=1 and count25=0,if third person has 25$ bill->count50=1 and count25=1,if fourth person have 100$bill->count50=0 and count25=0

```
public class Line {
    public static String Tickets(int[] peopleInLine) {
        int count25 = 0;
        int count50 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
            if (peopleInLine[i] == 100) {
                if (count25 == 1 && count50 > 0) {
                    count25 = count25 - 1;
                    count50 = count50 - 1;
                }

                if (count25 >= 3) {
                    count25 = count25 - 3;
                } else {
                    return "NO";
                }
            }

            if (peopleInLine[i] == 25) {
                count25 = count25 + 1;
            }

            if (peopleInLine[i] == 50) {
                count50 = count50 + 1;
                count25 = count25 - 1;
                if (count25 < 0) {
                    return "NO";
                }
            }
        }
        return "YES";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you get someone with 100 dollar bill and you have 2 25s and one 50? You should be able to give him change but i dont see an option for this.

Comment: Well, what are the values of the critical variables when you issue the **NO** response?  I see no attempt to debug this.

Comment: @JackVanier, i did a mistake in the code

Comment: @Prune, variables for  the test cases were not shown.

Comment: @CryBaby, I asked about your variables, not the test case values.  You identified a case where your code gives the wrong answer: 25, 50, 25, 100.  Then you showed how it *should* work.  I expect to see the results of your basic debugging attempts, tracing the quantities in your "cash box" as you serve each customer.

Comment: i don't know what happened ,but i rewrote the code and it worked.The test case which my code was falling was {25,25,25,25,50,100,50}. When a  person pays the clerk 50$ ,he can return him 25$ ,now he has three 25$  and one 50$. When person in the line pays clerk 100$ he can return 75$ as three 25$ bills or a 50$bill and a 25$ bill ,but if he pays the customer with three 25$ bill then he wont have money to pay for the next customer who is having a 50$ bill.So in other words clerk should try to preserve those 25$ bill.

Answer (score 1):

The second if statement in the 100 dollar bill case (`if(count25>=3)`) should not be evaluated if the first if statement (`if(count25==1&&count50>0)`) evaluates to `true`.

Use `else if` for the second condition :

```
if (peopleInLine[i] == 100) {
    if(count25 == 1 && count50 > 0) {
        count25--;
        count50--;
    } else if (count25 >= 3) {
        count25-=3;
    } else {
        return "NO";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String checkTicketChangePossible(int[] ticketPrices){
      String returnValue = "YES";
      int bill_25 = 0;
      int bill_50 = 0;

      for(int i= 0; i< ticketPrices.length; i++){
          if(ticketPrices[i] == 25){
              bill_25 += 1;
          }
          if(ticketPrices[i] == 50){
              bill_25 -= 1;
              bill_50 += 1;
          }
          if(ticketPrices[i] == 100){
              if(bill_50 == 0 && bill_25 >3){
                bill_25 -= 3;
              }else{
                bill_25 -= 1; bill_50 -= 1;
              }
          }

          if(bill_25 < 0 || bill_50 <0){
             returnValue = "NO";
             break;
          }

      }
      return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, this answer mainly consists of code. To make this answer more useful to future users, please consider adding explanatory text.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String checkTicketChangePossible(int[] ticketPrices){
  String returnValue = "YES";
  int bill_25 = 0;
  int bill_50 = 0;

  for(int i= 0; i< ticketPrices.length; i++){
      if(ticketPrices[i] == 25){
          bill_25 += 1;
      }
      if(ticketPrices[i] == 50){
          bill_25 -= 1;
          bill_50 += 1;
      }
      if(ticketPrices[i] == 100){
          if(bill_50 == 0 && bill_25 >= 3){
            bill_25 -= 3;
          }else{
            bill_25 -= 1; bill_50 -= 1;
          }
      }

      if(bill_25 < 0 || bill_50 <0){
         returnValue = "NO";
         break;
      }

  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.